# Client certificates for advance security and resource privacy

Tags: certificate, client-certificates

> In my web based application I'm looking for a way that enables only
>   some of the user to connect how have special client certificate installed
>   on their browser.

I'm very new to this field and already searched it on Google but all resources found are confusing and failed to provide what should be done to setup this kind of structure, I'm just looking for any expert who have ground knowledge on this any education links and articles suggested are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [two-way (or mutual) authentication with TLS](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=two+way+ssl+authentication).

Here is a [step-by-step guide](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/34925) for a manual trial on Linux-derived systems.